# move the variable ''x'' 12 cell down in ''for each x in y''

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code to automatically write information in a specific cell if there is matching information between a main list and a masterlist.

This is the main list which will be printed.
[image: main list]

And this is the masterlist which is a bank of components.

[image: masterlist]

in my test, the information i am trying to compare would be "test" cells C3 and C180 and "test2" cells C15 and C191 and the information to be written is a183:C189 to A6:C12 and A194:C200 to A18:C24 if there is a match.

Here is part of the code i have written :

```
Sub FR_3_08_Filerie_remplissage_automatique()

'sélection worksheet
Set filerie = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR-3-08_Filerie")

'tableau liste filerie colonne 1
Dim tableau_fi1 As range
Dim nbrligne_fi1 As Integer
Set tableau_fi1 = filerie.range("c3:c75")
nbrligne_fi1 = tableau_fi1.Rows.Count

'tableau liste filerie colonne 2
Dim tableau_fi2 As range
Dim nbrligne_fi2 As Integer
Set tableau_fi2 = filerie.range("n3:n75")
nbrligne_fi2 = tableau_fi2.Rows.Count

'tableau catalogue carte
Dim tableau_cc As range
Dim nbrligne_cc As Integer
Set tableau_cc = filerie.range("c180:c191")
nbrligne_cc = tableau_cc.Columns.Count

'recherche du duplicata
Dim masterlist As range

'code start


For k = 1 To nbrligne_fi1

    If IsEmpty(tableau_fi1(k, 1)) = False Then 'si cellule vide skip
    
        Set carte_actif = tableau_fi1(k, 1) 'mise en mémoire du composant de la cellule actif du tableau de filerie
        
        For Each masterlist In tableau_cc 'recherche de duplicata dans le catalogue de carte
    
            If carte_actif.Value = masterlist.Value Then 'si il y a duplicata, écriture de information
    
                'mise en mémoire des cellules utilisé dans les 2 tableaux
                Set couleur1 = carte_actif.Offset(3, 0)
                Set couleur2 = carte_actif.Offset(5, 0)
                Set couleur3 = carte_actif.Offset(7, 0)
                Set couleur4 = carte_actif.Offset(9, 0)
                Set mcouleur1 = tableau_cc.Offset(3, 0)
                Set mcouleur2 = tableau_cc.Offset(5, 0)
                Set mcouleur3 = tableau_cc.Offset(7, 0)
                Set mcouleur4 = tableau_cc.Offset(9, 0)
                
                Set deg1 = carte_actif.Offset(3, -1)
                Set deg2 = carte_actif.Offset(5, -1)
                Set deg3 = carte_actif.Offset(7, -1)
                Set deg4 = carte_actif.Offset(9, -1)
                Set mdeg1 = tableau_cc.Offset(3, -1)
                Set mdeg2 = tableau_cc.Offset(5, -1)
                Set mdeg3 = tableau_cc.Offset(7, -1)
                Set mdeg4 = tableau_cc.Offset(9, -1)
                
                Set qty1 = carte_actif.Offset(3, -2)
                Set qty2 = carte_actif.Offset(5, -2)
                Set qty3 = carte_actif.Offset(7, -2)
                Set qty4 = carte_actif.Offset(9, -2)
                Set mqty1 = tableau_cc.Offset(3, -2)
                Set mqty2 = tableau_cc.Offset(5, -2)
                Set mqty3 = tableau_cc.Offset(7, -2)
                Set mqty4 = tableau_cc.Offset(9, -2)
                
                'écriture de l'information dans le tableau couple de serrage
                couleur1.Value = mcouleur1.Value
                couleur2.Value = mcouleur2.Value
                couleur3.Value = mcouleur3.Value
                couleur4.Value = mcouleur4.Value
                
                deg1.Value = mdeg1.Value
                deg2.Value = mdeg2.Value
                deg3.Value = mdeg3.Value
                deg4.Value = mdeg4.Value
                
                qty1.Value = mqty1.Value
                qty2.Value = mqty2.Value
                qty3.Value = mqty3.Value
                qty4.Value = mqty4.Value
                        
            End If
            
        Next masterlist

    End If
    
    k = k + 11
    
Next k

End Sub
```

The variable i am trying to move is ''masterlist'' in `For Each masterlist In tableau_cc` down 11 cells each loop which would move from test to test2 in the image bank of components. Else the code tries to verify each cell between the 2 which take more time for the code to finish.

I tried code like `masterlist = masterlist.offset(11, 0)` but it copies the information in C191 to c180.

I also played with .end(xdown) by moving C180 and C191 to ''E'' but i have the same problem and a new 1 by having for example `Set deg1 = carte_actif.Offset(3, -1)` broken. the -1 and any other number work but when i enter -3 i get an error which is what i need...

what would be the solution to move ''masterlist'' in the code 12 cells down each loop?

EDIT:

the range written is for test purpose as the range will grow as i add more component in my list. currently it is "C180:C279" but could go to C400 in the future. it is the reason i am trying to move the variable "masterlist" 11 row down each loop.

currently i am using `Set tableau_cc = filerie.range("c180, c191, c202, c213, c224, c235, c246, c257, c268, c279")` as a solution to force verification on specific cell insteal of the whole range. i will have to add manualy each cell as i expand the masterlist with more component. also added a `exit for` after the information has been transfered to make the loop faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but should be close:

```vb
Sub FR_3_08_Filerie_remplissage_automatique()

    Dim wb As Workbook, filerie As Worksheet, cModel As Range, i As Long
    Dim model, cMatch As Range, matched As Boolean, rw As Long, col As Long
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set filerie = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR-3-08_Filerie")
    
    Set cModel = filerie.Range("C3") 'first model value to search for
    Do
        i = i + 1
        If Len(cModel.Value) > 0 Then            'anything to look for?
            Set cMatch = filerie.Range("C180")   'first cell to match on
            Do While cMatch.Row < 400            'adjust max row as needed
                If cMatch.Value = cModel.Value Then
                    For col = -2 To 0
                        For rw = 2 To 8 Step 2
                            cModel.Offset(rw, col).Value = cMatch.Offset(rw, col).Value
                        Next rw
                    Next col
                End If
                Set cMatch = cMatch.Offset(11)
            Loop
        End If
        
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then
            Set cModel = cModel.Offset(0, 11)   'move over to the right
        Else
            Set cModel = cModel.Offset(12, -11) 'move down and back to the left
        End If
    
    Loop While cModel.Row < 80
    
End Sub
```

Comment: i had to do some modification but it is working. here what i did : `For rw = 1 To 8 Step 2`, `cModel.Offset(rw + 2, col).Value = cMatch.Offset(rw + 2, col).Value` and i added `Exit Do` after `next col` to exit the loop when a match is found. i had problem at start because of fused cell with the line bellow `If i Mod 2 = 1 Then` but when i found this problem it whent smooth

Answer (score 0):

try below with check of last row with test name in column C starting at C180

```
    Option Explicit

Sub copy()
Dim lRow As Long, i, x, dn, rt, y
 
Do While Range("C" & Range("C180").Row + i) <> ""
i = i + 11
Loop

lRow = Range("C" & Range("C180").Row + i).Row - 11 ' the last row with test name

 For x = 180 To lRow Step 11
    If Range("C" & x) = Range("C" & Range("C3").Row + y) Then
        For dn = 3 To 9 Step 2
            For rt = 0 To -2 Step -1
                    Range("C" & Range("C3").Row + y).Offset(dn, rt) = Range("C" & x).Offset(dn, rt)
            Next rt
        Next dn
    End If
y = y + 12
 Next x
 
End Sub
```

Comment: the cell and value i refered to was for test purpose as it is a range of cell hat need to be checked to see if there is a match of information. the match that need to be verified is bettwen `.range("c3:c75")` and `.range("c180:c279")`. currently in my code `.range("c3:c75")` move 11 cell down each time with the code `For k = 1 To nbrligne_fi1` and `k = k + 11`, i need to do the same thing with '.range("c180:c279")' but i cant find a way to move the variable masterlist 12 cell down each loop.

Comment: the current solution that i found 30 min ago is `Set tableau_cc = filerie.range("c180, c191, c202, c213, c224, c235, c246, c257, c268, c279")` as it force to  verify specific cell instead of all cell in the range. the only incovenient is to add each cell manualy as i expand the code and add more component to my master list

Comment: see if the updated code above suits your need, also a suggestion it is best not to merge cells as much as possible